# How to place uib-datepicker inside <select>

Tags: angularjs, html

I use `AngularJs` and like to display `<select>` if dates are available, if not I like to put `uib-datepicker` inside `<select>`.

Let me explain again, if dates are available clicking `<select>` makes dates are coming out, if dates are not available, clicking `<select>` will make `uib-datepicker` display.

[image: dates]
[image]

I have html code for `multi-datepicker.tpl.html`.

```
<div class="uib-datepicker" ng-switch="datepickerMode" role="application" ng-keydown="keydown($event)">
    <uib-daypicker ng-switch-when="day" tabindex="0" template-url="app/travels/views/multi-day.tpl.html"></uib-daypicker>
    <uib-monthpicker ng-switch-when="month" tabindex="0"></uib-monthpicker>
    <uib-yearpicker ng-switch-when="year" tabindex="0"></uib-yearpicker>
</div>
```

For that what I did in my html code is

```
<div class="row travel-reviews">
    <select ng-model="selectedSeats" ng-change="totalAmountCal()" ng-options="seat as seat.seat for seat in seats">
         <option value="" selected disabled>Select no of seats </option>
    </select>
    <select  ng-show="dateLength" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-options="date as date for date in selectedDates">
          <option value="" selected disabled>Select date </option>
     </select>
     <select  ng-show="!dateLength" >
           <uib-datepicker ng-model='selectedDate' multi-select='selectedDates' template-url='app/travels/views/multi-datepicker.tpl.html'></uib-datepicker>
     </select> 

 </div>
```

Now the problem are (1) datepicker is not in the select and (2) second one overwrite the first one.

How to solve the problem? When dates are available `$scope.dateLength is true` and not available `$scope.dateLength is false.`

EDIT:

```
<div class="row travel-reviews">
    <select ng-model="selectedSeats" ng-change="totalAmountCal()" ng-options="seat as seat.seat for seat in seats">
         <option value="" selected disabled>Select no of seats </option>
    </select>
    <select  ng-show="dateLength" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-options="date as date for date in selectedDates">
         <option value="" selected disabled>Select date </option>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="!dateLength">
        <b style="font-size:15px; color:blue">Please select date</b>                                     
        <section>
             <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <uib-datepicker ng-model='selectedDate' multi-select='selectedDates' template-url='app/travels/views/multi-datepicker.tpl.html'></uib-datepicker>
                    </td>
                    <td style='width:10px'></td>
                 </tr>
                </table>
                </section>
             </div>
       </div>
```

multi-day.tpl.html

```
    <table class="uib-daypicker" role="grid" aria-labelledby="{{::uniqueId}}-title" aria-activedescendant="{{activeDateId}}">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left uib-left" ng-click="move(-1)" tabindex="-1">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                    </button>
                </th>
                <th colspan="{{::5 + showWeeks}}">
                    <button id="{{::uniqueId}}-title" role="heading" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm uib-title" ng-click="toggleMode()" ng-disabled="datepickerMode === maxMode" tabindex="-1">
                        <strong>{{title}}</strong>
                    </button>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right uib-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center"></th>
                <th ng-repeat="label in ::labels track by $index" class="text-center">
                    <small aria-label="{{::label.full}}">{{::label.abbr}}</small>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="uib-weeks" ng-repeat="row in rows track by $index">
                <td ng-if="showWeeks" class="text-center h6">
                    <em>{{ weekNumbers[$index] }}</em>
                </td>
                <td ng-repeat="dt in row" class="uib-day text-center" role="gridcell" id="{{::dt.uid}}" ng-class="::dt.customClass">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-info': dt.selected, active:    isActive(dt)}" ng-click="select(dt.date)" ng-disabled="::dt.disabled" tabindex="-1">
                        <span ng-class="::{'text-muted': dt.secondary, 'text-info': dt.current}">{{::dt.label}}</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[image]

Comment: I did as shown in the last image. If dates are available, select will display with dates. If not date picker will come out. I need to add multi-day.tpl.html. Still need to make the date picker smaller and fit to the small form.

Comment: So you need to style datepicker popup, no?

Comment: @Leguest how to style to fit into the form. I have a discussion here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786762/how-to-display-correctly-angular-bootstraps-datepicker)